# Sklearn Preprocessing Error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'decimal' codec can't encode characters

Tags: python, unicode, scikit-learn, preprocessor

When I run a scaler based in sklearn preprocessing, I receive an error that looks like this:(Environment：python 2_7   numpy (1_12_1)   pandas (0_20_2)   scikit-learn (0_18_1) )

The code is I use presented below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing

data=pd.read_excel('article_category.xlsx')
data.head()

X = np.array(data['article'])
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)
```

The output is the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 
560, in fit
return self.partial_fit(X, y)
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 583, in partial_fit
estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)

File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 382, in check_array
array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'decimal' codec can't encode characters in position 0-178: invalid decimal Unicode string
```

data.head() 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/2whDk.png

Comment: Can you upload the xlsx file ? What does the array X contain ? Numbers ? Strings ? I guess you have strings ?

Comment: Most scikit estimators and transformers only work with numerical data. But you have non-number data in the `X`. First you need a way to convert them into numbers, then you can use the `StandardScaler`.